# After upgrading to Ag-grid 30 I have a problem with the moveColumns function

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I upgraded ag grid version from 27 to 30 and now columnApi.moveColumns function does not work for me as it used to. The function does not seem to change the order.

I think I was able to reproduce the situation in this [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/mRhi6YP8VhTK8jt8)
In my case the code is

```
this.gridColumnApi.moveColumns(['selected', 'ag-Grid-AutoColumn'], 0);
```

But I modified an aggrid code example to resemble what I'm trying to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you help me understand?  Does the plunker provided do what you need?  If not, what do you want it to do?

Comment: I expect the 'age' column to appear before 'athlete'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setTimeout solved the problem

```
setTimeout(() => this.gridColumnApi.moveColumns(['selected', 'ag-Grid-AutoColumn'], 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the ag-grid team solved this issue in v30.0.6, if you do not want to use the setTimeout solution